# Nginx directory and index file configuration like Apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I decided to try Nginx on my local machine and it turned out to be quite a pain in one place.

Before Nginx, I was using Apache and my root folder was configured to be `/var/www/html`.  Server name was `localhost`. This means that going to `localhost/project`, it opened what's inside `/var/www/html/project` and all worked perfectly.

However on Nginx I configured my root and server name absolutely the same ( `root = /var/www/html` and `server_name = localhost` ) and I'm expecting same results like Apache.

The problem is that only homepage of subdirectory works. For example, `localhost/project` works, but `localhost/project/foo` returns 404.

If I configure root to be root of project (`root = /var/www/html/project`), then I can access `localhost/project/foo` perfectly and all works fine.

What's the catch here?  Is it supposed to be like this or there could be something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what files you have and where.  Is your index configured correctly?  Is `foo` a file or directory?  If directory, what happens when you add the trailing slash `/`?

Comment: Here is my config -> https://gist.github.com/archonkulis/ac6351b647d1a286582a

Note that there are few commented try_files lines. I have tried them all, didn't get expected results from any of those.

Comment: @Brad it's a controller action. Project is on laravel framework. So, it has MVC structure and if I understood everything correctly, every request goes through projects index.php file.

It does work however, if I create a folder and some php file and try to access it.

Uhh, now I'm even more confused as I thought it doesn't matter what.

Comment: @user3722573 Ah, you should add that detail to your question.  That is important information to know.  Laravel has a fairly large config file you need to get it working in Nginx.  I don't have a copy on me at the moment, but if you search around, you will find it.

Comment: @Brad yeah, I didn't mention that because I didn't thought that it matters, but I tried creating folder with php file inside laravels public folder. And I can access it fine. So yeah... to be honest I'm now even more confused

Comment: First, try the Nginx config file for Laravel.  It will likely work right out of the box.  If it doesn't, make a PHP file in your document root and try to access it directly and explicitly.  This is to confirm that PHP is working.  Next, make sure your rewrites are pointed at your PHP files.  You can do this by putting a statement like `print_r($_REQUEST); die();` at the very top of your script.  Once you have done this, go the rewritten URL.  You should get a page with all of the parameters sent to it from the rewrite (if any).  If that's working, start poking around at your Laravel config.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i recommend to you use a virtual host for each application. But in this case you can put the value "autoindex on" inside your location / configuration.... like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
    autoindex on;

}
```

Enjoy Nginx :) is much better

Comment: That is what I tried to not to do. I understand that in real life server it is a must, but I kind of got used to "localhost/project" kind of thing ;) Anyway, thanks for autoindex, will try some time soon.